# Sending files from site to google drive using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I wrote a code that can add files to google drive. Set up all my data in the google console. When I try to add my file to google drive, it uploads fine, I get a success message
`File uploaded successfully: { id: '1NdVZAgSMxHSH_aCW94uyVMVrfWP8G6SY', name: 'CV.pdf' }`
But the file itself is not sent to my disk, but do not understand where. Who has experienced this? I already added access from the client_email e-mail to the Google drive folder, which I registered in the credentials of the Google console itself, but this did not help me. Who can tell you exactly how to upload a file to your Google drive?

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import fs from 'fs'
import { Readable } from 'stream'
import path from 'path'

const filePath = path.resolve('./key.json')

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: filePath,
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
})

const uploadFiles = async () => {
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync('public/name.jpg')
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth })

    drive.files.create({
        requestBody: {
            name: 'name.jpg',
            mimeType: 'image/jpg',
            parents: "1WZj-6PV6sschMMBUFZax-O8ImCqTE7uC"
        },
        media: {
            mimeType: 'image/jpg',
            body: Readable.from(fileContents)
        }
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('File uploaded successfully:', res.data);
    })
}
```

I tried different ways, re-created Google accounts, looked at other people's guides, did everything they had, but the files never got to my disk